# How are practice areas communicated?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, flight-school

When I fly near my local airport (`KSSF`) in San Antonio, there's a designated South Practice Area and North Practice Area. ATC knows where they are and all the flight schools at the airport seem to have a common idea of their boundaries.

However, they aren't marked anywhere on charts or supplements and I can't seem to find any information online. I was wondering how these are communicated between different entities (control towers, ARTCCs, flight schools) - are they standardized at all? Is there anywhere I can find information?

Comment: Based on my personal experience, the established (and apparently FAA-sanctioned) procedure is to get on the glider frequency 123.5 and constantly call out your location every couple of minutes, much to the annoyance of every glider pilot within radio range.

Answer (score 2):

Some practice areas are charted, e.g. there's one near Hillsboro, OR. The VFR sectional has this note just northwest of the Newberg VOR:

[image]

If you then look up the Chart Supplement, there are more details on the area and the frequency to use:

[image]

Note that 122.75 is the [general air-to-air frequency for the US](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9379/62), it isn't a specific frequency for that area.

Having said that, many practice areas are informal and they rely on local knowledge. That could be a documented agreement between ATC and flight schools, or an informal arrangement between local instructors. I have no idea who determines which areas are worth charting.

As far as I know, there's no specific regulation or central FAA control of practice areas, with the exception of [aerobatic practice areas](https://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/8700.1%20ga%20ops%20insp%20handbk/volume%202/2_048_00.htm).